# after run php bin/magento module:disable --all my setup become messy

Tags: magento2, testing, uninstall-module

in my local setup 
I have run the command for testing, what happens.

> php bin/magento module:disable --all
>   I have found an error in most of commands and nothing is working.

[image: php bin/magento module:disable --all]

after that, I have run

> php bin/magento module:enable -all

I have found the error in command-line

[image: magento messy setup]

in db core_config_data table is missing.

I have tried this for fun but never try this ....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable all 3-rd parties modules you can run this command :

> php bin/magento module:status | grep -v Magento | grep -v List | grep
>   -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:disable

This will keep only the Magento core modules enabled .

You should not have issues with `setup:upgrade` command .

**Note !** (Captcha module might not be disabled , if it throws an error , disable it manually )

Answer (score 1):

Use of `module:disable --all` means disabled all module.

And after that you have tried to enable again `php bin/magento module:enable -all` 
 As the minimum modules which is required for run Magento system also disabled during disabling modules. You did the wrong.

Also in process some tables also removed that why you getting error.

For this case, you must need to remove the database and create a new fresh Magento install.